# My manager goes through my old and incomplete scripts and critiques them - is this valid?

Tags: software-industry, project-management

My manager will call me into his office about once every week or two and have one of my scripts I wrote just for myself, or started and didn't end up finishing or using, up on his emacs. He'll go over every line and tell me it's inefficient or incorrect, or just run something blindly and complain that it gave an error when it's something obvious like an unclosed for loop. Is this valid criticism? I always say that it's not finished or abandoned, or that I'm in the middle of working on it and that's why there are bugs. It's like he doesn't hear me saying anything because he'll just say it's unprofessional to have these low quality scripts in my home directory. What would you recommend doing about this?

Comment: Not having them in the home directory.

Comment: What is your manager doing in your home directory?

Comment: If they aren't for your manager's eyes, don't leave them where your manager can find them.

Comment: It's of course valid. Your manager has the power to review anything belongs to the company. Your scripts are company assets.

Comment: Automatically put an all-caps comment block at the start of all your scripts saying, "INCOMPLETE; DO NOT USE". You can change it when it's ready...or just leave it.

Comment: Can you password each file? Or limit his read access?

Comment: Why does he have access to your home directory?

Comment: Have you asked your manager why he's looking at these scripts and giving you feedback?

Comment: This kind of behavior is silly, but if you want to try to live with it use file locations that make the purpose clear, such as ~/ugly_temporary_hacks/bad_idea.sh and if that doesn't work let them stumble upon ~/resume_update.odt

Comment: Please don't post answers here

Comment: OP: What do you want to happen? Do you want to limit code review to some fraction of your work? Do you want to know why your manager doing this?

Comment: *...he'll just say it's unprofessional to have these low quality scripts in my home directory.* Have you asked your boss why he thinks it's unprofessional? Have you asked him where he'd like you to keep code that either isn't finished or is only for your own use?

Comment: Sounds like a very very bored manager.

Answer (score 4):

### Case 1: The location of the code is intended to be a repository used by others

Having your manager review this code is perfectly valid.

However, there should be a clear separation between complete actively-used code and incomplete or abandoned code, and your home directory should not be used as a repository for others. If there is no such separation and your home directory is intended to be a repository, I would recommend pushing for a better way to store your code. Although you'd still need to keep your home directory clean until a better alternative is adopted.

### Case 2: The location is considered private for the most part

Such reviews wouldn't be particularly appropriate, nor would it be appropriate for them to regularly browse around there for no good reason (which is not to say you should expect this location to be private).

Your manager might be doing it because:

- They're trying to help you, but it really doesn't make sense to review abandoned or incomplete code.
- They're bored, but they shouldn't be making this your problem.
- They're trying to belittle you, or they have some other nefarious purpose, which would obviously just be inappropriate.

However, the reason for this wouldn't matter much (except in terms of how hard you should be looking for another job). The problem would remain regardless of reason.

## If you're not sure what the location of the code is intended for

I'd suggest clarifying this with your manager.

## What can you do about it?

- **During the review, tell them you're still busy working on these scripts** (which you've already done)

  I would hesitate to say they're "abandoned", because that raises the question of why you haven't deleted them yet, unless you follow that up with "hold on, let me quickly go and delete it" (if your manager insists on holding the review anyway, you might consider responding to any critique by repeatedly saying it's obsolete and should be deleted, although that would probably come across as passive aggressive).
- **Find somewhere else to put your incomplete code** (which is ideally only accessible by you)

  In case #1, you should put it in a location that isn't intended to be a repository used by others. If you cannot find or create such a location, you can't do much more than asking your manager to recommend where to put it (which would also highlight that you have nowhere else to put it). This would also apply if that location is the only place where you can back-up code. It wouldn't make any sense to not have a place to put code that's incomplete (which would apply to any code you're still working on).

  In either case, in the absence of another option, you can consider putting incomplete scripts in a directory named `INCOMPLETE` and/or adding a few TODO's to the code.
- **Ask them what the purpose of the review is, and follow up appropriately**

  If they say it's to help you improve your coding, you can respond by saying you already know the things they're saying (assuming this is true).

  If they just say your home directory should be "clean", or something to that extent, you can ask them why and lead this back to a discussion of either:

  - Whether it's supposed to be viewed by others.
  - Or how the current state of these scripts (that exist only for your personal use) is optimal for your productivity, given that taking time to maintain them would affect your ability to get more important work done. Probably not in those exact words though.
- **Accept the reviews and fix the code**

  Failing the above, or finding another job, there isn't much else you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not it is a valid criticism or not is irrelevant.  The fact of the matter is that your manager has access to your home directory, you know he has access to your home directory, yet you are still leaving items in your home directory that you know he will confront you about and criticize.

Depending on the structure of your company, you need to check if your manager is even supposed to have access to your home directory.  If there is some security team at your company you can approach them and ask if correct procedures are being followed.

In the meantime, since you know your manager will look at your files and you don't want him to, you need to leave the files somewhere else where he cannot easily access them or encrypt them.

Comment: This is missing the fundamental point: productive work requires a *scratchpad* one can use *without fear* while contemplating *legitimate* business problems.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this valid criticism?

Well technically, yes. He is just doing a code review of code in a repository he has access to.

> Is this a dick move?

Also yes, this is very much a move that seems calculated to belittle you. Especially as he seems to be doing this on a regular basis.

I'd be running for the hills the second time this happened.

But assuming your boss is more stupid than malicious and you would like to stay at your job:
Apparently his issue is mainly that you are leaving these scripts laying about, although I'm just interpreting this from your post. You should ask him what would fix this. Maybe you can make a "PascLeRasc's stuff, deprecated, don't touch" folder or move all your stuff to some local place out of your manager's sight.

Comment: Mostly agree, though a strategy of having to hide your work from your manager smells of a toxic relationship that will never be productive.

Answer (score 1):

Change the permissions to your home dir and the scripts (unless there is a rule which keeps you from doing that).

If the manager uses administrative access to look into your home dir, you may want to look into the IT guidelines of your company if that is ok. If it is not (which i assume), then it depends a little bit on workplace culture, location, company size etc what to do and cant be answered without further details.

Answer (score 0):

Brush off your resume/CV.  Ideally, you’d be able to rationally discuss this, transfer teams, go to his boss, etc.  But he seems a micromanager who’s not sure what his role as a manager really is and wishes he was still coding.  He seems to take any defense as an attack on himself.  I don’t read anything in your explanation telling me he’s open to reason or him being anything but the superior.

Micromanagement is bad enough.  Using it simply as a way to belittle you is even worse.  And possibly even worse is that in his brilliant “mentorship” he’s demonstrating he knows very little of the process and application of proofs of concept or ad hoc scripts designed to save you minutes or hours at the expense of maybe costing a processor 6 more seconds on the rare occasion you do run it.

**UPDATE**  Changing jobs is almost always a knee-jerk reaction vs. other less drastic things.  But do be prepared for that being the outcome.  After being ready, schedule a meeting with your boss.  You're requesting his guidance as to where you can reasonably shelve tools and snippets that are for pragmatic and POC needs but not intended to be honed, released or tuned for frequent execution.  A tone of recognizing his authority and wanting to learn from his experience may help.

If he is not how I interpreted him based on the frequency and immutability of view, 1) you may get the answer as to where to shield such tools from production-candidate scrutiny, 2) you will demonstrate a desire to improve and 3) by being a different setting he may better process that you grasp quality code and there may be a distinction.

If he is closer to my original interpretation, see the part about dusting off your resume/CV.  He may think you just don't understand all these golden nuggets he's been trying to provide and may be a block to you transferring and hold it against you at review time.

Comment: Ah, the old favourite response: "Some tiny thing wrong with your job? Get a new one!".

Comment: @DJClayworth I have to disagree that a boss showing a regular pattern of micromanagement and inflexibility, while providing feedback that will reflect negatively on performance reviews is a minor thing to overlook.  Had the OP stated, "This happened for the first time yesterday, how should I handle it?" it would have been much different.  This is a pattern and one that isn't changing in the person who holds the most sway over the OP's job.